# Datetime's strftime formatting incorrectly

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to display a date in the Brazilian locale `dd/mm/yyyy`. I used datetime's `srtftime("%x")` function but what I'm getting is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Here's the code I used to test it:

```
>>> import locale
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> locale.getlocale()
('pt_BR', 'cp1252')
>>> today = dt.date.today()
>>> today.strftime('%x')
'10/07/13'
```

It should be `07/10/13`.

I can do it with:

```
>>> today.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
'07/10/13'
```

But I'm just wondering why it didn't work in the "correct" way.

Comment: This works for me: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR')`. Then `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%x")` -- produces `07-10-2013`

Comment: @MarkkuK. I get an error when trying the first line.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\locale.py", line 539, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
Error: unsupported locale setting`

I'm on Windows by the way...

Comment: what is your python version and OS?

Comment: How about `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Portuguese_Brazil')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `locale.setlocale(category,locale)` second parameter must be recognizable, otherwise you get 'Error: unsupported locale setting' error.
You can use:

```
print( locale.locale_alias)
```

to get a dictionary of proper locale aliases, but not all of these locales have to be available. On my Windows machine it's 'portuguese_brazil' and then for

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'portuguese_brazil')
today = dt.date.today()
today.strftime('%x')
print(today)
```

output:

> > > 2013-10-07